# VB.NET Combination of For Each..Next and Do..While

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have an array like so:

```
Dim classes() as String = {"FR%", "SO", "JR", "SR", "SR5"}
```

I need to loop through these values like so:

```
For Each value as String in classes

Next
```

Problem is, I have a If..Then..Else clause inside of this For Each..Next which says something to the effect of:

```
If actual_class = value Then
  txt.Text = "Welcome"
Else
  txt.Text = "Goodbye"
```

When I run this, unless the individual is the last value in the string array ("SR5") they are going to get the message "Goodbye"...so, I need somehow to both iterate through each value like is done with a For Each..Next loop but also break out of the loop once it hits the student's class, like a Do..While loop - so that their value doesn't get overrun by the Else clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want to break out of the loop do `Exit For`

See [For Each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) and [Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47.aspx)

**Updated Example**

```
txt.Text = "Goodbye"

For Each value as String in classes
    If actual_class = value Then
        txt.Text = "Welcome"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. I'm still always getting the second message. Is it possible that placing a Exit For within a If..Then causes the Exit For not to work? It seems like the Exit For is never being executed.

Comment: Yes you can have the Exit For within the If, so if you want to stop processing after setting txt.Text = "Welcome" place the Exit For after that statement

Comment: Have you tried debugging the process, and seeing how the actual flow of the program goes? If you haven't, do so now.

Comment: I have, and I'm not seeing anything. I have the two variables being compared current_value and value set as strings, and I can see that they are equivalent during debug.

Comment: BTW, I've placed a Response.Write("hello") within the clause that should trigger - and it is triggering b/c it writes hello to the screen, but it is still executing the Else clause even though I have an Exit For statement in the first code block!

Comment: @davemackey Sounds like something else outside your loop is updating the result variable or the loop is getting called again and overwriting the original result.

Comment: @Hadley, yeah, that is what it seems like...but I've searched the whole project (which I also wrote) and there aren't any other references or instances in which it would be set to this value...but I'll accept your answer - since you answered my initial question and open a new question for this issue. Thanks!

Comment: here is the followup question with an extensive source code posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380759/for-next-exit-for-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

```
txt.Text = ""

For Each value as String in classes
    If actual_class = value Then
        txt.Text = "Welcome"
    Else
        txt.Text = "Goodbye"
    End If
Next
```